# How to Save an Image of a Large Flex Component (EX: 25000px by 3000px @ 72dpi)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

My application consists of displaying a large custom tree like structure to the user that can eventually grow to massive proportions like the dimensions listed in the question. I allow them to export the image with the following line of code tied to a button click event:

```
var image:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(this, 72, new PNGEncoder(), false);
```

I've managed to export images close to the dimensions listed but around there it start to get the error message listed below after spinning for close to 15 seconds:

```
Error: Error #1000: The system is out of memory.
    at flash.utils::ByteArray/writeBytes()
    at mx.graphics::ImageSnapshot$/mergePixelRows()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\graphics\ImageSnapshot.as:511]
    at mx.graphics::ImageSnapshot$/captureAll()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\graphics\ImageSnapshot.as:482]
    at mx.graphics::ImageSnapshot$/captureImage()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\graphics\ImageSnapshot.as:318]
    at vertical/saveChart()[C:\devel\workspace\vertical\src\CustomObject.mxml:501]
    at vertical/__saveImageBtn_click()[C:\devel\workspace\vertical\src\CustomObject.mxml:574]
```

Is the flashplayer plugin for my browser running out of memory? I noticed in my task manager it got up to about 1.2GB of memory usage(I have 4GB on my system). If that is the case is it possible to limit the memory usage for a given function like the `ImageSnapshot.captureImage()` call above?

Is there maybe a way to generate the component into 2 or 4 `ImageSnapshot` objects and piece them together afterward?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With a dimension of 25000x3000, you're looking at at least 214MB *just to hold the raw bitmap data* (that's assuming the minimum of three RGB bytes per pixel -- add another 71MB for transparent bitmaps). Chances are that any manipulation you're doing to the image will end up copying this data a few times. You'll probably need to modify the classes you're using to do things in batches (look for an async PNG encoder). And even then, there'll be a single gigantic call to `ByteArray.compress()` in whatever PNG encoder you choose.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the latest Flash Player 11 has a new feature to solve this issue:

"Enhanced high resolution bitmap support — BitmapData objects are no longer limited to a maximum resolution of 16 megapixels (16,777,215 pixels), and maximum bitmap width/height is no longer limited to 8,191 pixels, enabling the development of apps that utilize very large bitmaps." from [this PDF](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplatformruntimes/shared/flashplayer11_air3_b1_releasenotes_071311.pdf)

Comment: Interesting, so that route would be converting the component to BitmapData first, then to a ByteArray and finally encoding it into a png/jpg correct? Flashplayer 11 is still in beta though and I won't be able to use this until it has an official release. If no one else has an idea/solution then I'll give this route a go and if it does end up working I can put this portion of the software on hold until FP11 comes out hopefully soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BitmapData, it makes a difference which FlashPlayer you are targetting:

**versions VS maximum bitmapsize**

flashplayer -9 : 2880x2880 px
   flashplayer 10 : 4096x4096 px
   flashplayer 11 :   unlimited

I don't know what you exactly are trying to do with this huge capture, but I would recommend using tiles. Break it down to chunks of relative small bitmaps. Create them separately, so you don't have to open/create that huge amount of data in your memory.

Anyway, it would be nice to know if it is possible to encode that big-ass sized image, without `Error #1000 out of memory` errors.